# Is it advisable or appropriate to use IPFS to store files(such as images) for Hyperledger Fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ipfs

Hi Fabric & IPFS experts:

I need to store some big files(images, videos) for hyperledger fabric network. It is not a good idea to use the fabric's own couchdb/goleveldb to store such big files. So some alternative solution should be investigated.

As we know, fabric is Consortium Blackchain, which means that the data is only stored in the organizations' peers. But it seems that files stored in IPFS are widely spread around the world(many IPFS peers), it is kind of like public storage.

So the question comes: Is it advisable or appropriate to use IPFS to store files(such as images) for Hyperledger Fabric network? Is there any security problem? Could you please provide some sights on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is very useful use IPFS to store large files, and you are right, it is not secure use the public network, but IPFS provide a way to create a private network, check this [link](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/experimental-features.md#private-networks)
And if you want to replicate data, check ipfs [cluster](https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs-cluster).